# Install multiple window services from a root executable file

Tags: c#, web-services

I built a window service name "A".
The window service will have different name for each installation.
I copy the Debug folder to serveral folders.
In each folder, I have a file "data.dat" with content "1,2,3,4" to specify service name.

I also write a test program to run all clone service with

```
ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper(string[])
```

method.
However, it give me error "The specified service already exists".

It means that my first clone folder has been installed, however, other folders keep the same name.

In ProjectInstaller.cs, I log the

```
currentLocation = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
```

to log the current executing folder.
All log gave me the same folders.

Then, I used Developper command of visual to install these services, it worked.

I dont know why?
Can you help me? Thank you!

Comment: Create some service config file and let installer read from there all the values that you need

Comment: Can you explain more clearly?
I have service_1 will read log_1.bat
service_2 will read log_2.bat
However, when I log the log:
the file path of service_1 is correct, the file path of service_2 and later will take service_1 path, so I can not read the log_2.bat to set the ServiceName

Comment: Again, not that your question is really clear, hence lack of response. This sounds to me that you want to install same exe as many unique services but it seem that you having problem to distinct them. What you use, installutil? When you create win service, it must have installer component that interfaces installutil. In that installer you need to specify unique name etc. But you don't want to compile 4 different EXEs. So, what you need is to supply some file, even app.config will do it. And during install phase, you read from that file unique service name, etc. Then, you can have many of same

Comment: My step is:
1. Create a window service:
2. Copy the debug folder to clone them into folder 1, folder 2, folder 3, folder 4.
3. Each clone folder has a unique file to define the service name.
4. I run a console app with code:
ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper(new string[]{"folder1\service.exe", "folder2\service.exe", "folder3\service.exe"});. Only service.exe in folder 1 is installed. Error for folder2 and folder 3 mean that the specified service has existed. It means that, exe file in folder2 and folder3 executed, but, the path always in folder1

Comment: However, when I install step by step for each folder, it works.
Meaning that,
I run console app with
ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper(new string[]{"folder1\service.exe"});
and then turn off console app.
Run console app again with ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper(new string[]{"folder2\service.exe"});
Similar to folder3, all 3 services have been installed.